# Quando devo usar let ou var em javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho observado em algumas aplicações javascript, o uso de `let`no lugar de `var`ao declarar uma variável.

Então estou tendo os seguintes questionamentos:

- Qual a diferença entre `let`e `var`
- Em qual momento devo usar um ou outro